# Unable to perform the 'rds_restore_database' procedure on AWS RDS SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, restore, amazon-rds

I'm facing the error `Maximum supported database size on SQL Server Express edition is: 10 GB.` when executing the restore procedure `msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database`.

The weird thing is the actual database seems not to hit the 10 GB size.
One indication of that is I can perform the restore on my local environment (using the same `.bak` file).

Furthermore, `sp_helpfile` confirms that the database size is smaller than 10GB, as showed on attached print.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2016 Express restore size limit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149313/sql-server-2016-express-restore-size-limit)

Comment: My guess is that there is some compression involved and at restore time, the database is created with a larger size than it will end up eventually. the "normal" restore command does just this for performance reasons, and you can disable it using a trace flag. Perhaps the RDS way will temporarily make it so but so the size limit prohibit the restore, then though the final size would be OK?

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for the ref. I tried the command `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/path/foo.bak'` and the `size` column is showing only `8,24 GB` (not counting the transactions log file).

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Seems a good guess, but I'm not getting the limitation error when restoring in my local environment. For testing purposes, I'll try to drop a significant volume of data and retry the backup/restore process.

Comment: Are you using msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database on your local environment? My guess is based on this proc does things differently than the native restore command.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi No! On local environment, I'm just using `RESTORE DATABASE [my_db] FROM DISK = '/path/foo.bak' WITH REPLACE...`.

Comment: I thought so. :-) So my theory is that the rds procedure does things differently in how the  database is created during restore (created initially larger than the end-result causing your error). I don't have the source code for this proc, so it is only a guess. Perhaps you can generate a backup without compression, or perhaps there's some compression related option for this proc...?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by shrinking the database. (Before export backup):

1. Click right about database
2. Task => Shrink => Files
3. Reorganize Pages... You should write the value minimum in mb.
4. Export Backup Again.

[image]